# Getting sub-scores for sub-queries in Lucene

Tags: java, scala, lucene

I have constructed a query that's essentially a weighted sum of other queries:

```
val query = new BooleanQuery
for ((subQuery, weight) <- ...) {
  subQuery.setBoost(weight)
  query.add(subQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST)
}
```

When I query the index, I get back documents with the overall scores. This is good, but I also need to know what the sub-scores for each of the sub-queries were. How can I get those? Here's what I'm doing now:

```
for (scoreDoc <- searcher.search(query, nHits).scoreDocs) {
  val score = scoreDoc.score
  val subScores = subQueries.map { subQuery =>
    val weight = searcher.createNormalizedWeight(subQuery)
    val scorer = weight.scorer(reader, true, true)
    scorer.advance(scoreDoc.doc)
    scorer.score
  }
}
```

I think this gives me the right scores, but it seems wasteful to advance to and re-score the document when I know it's already been scored as part of the overall score.

Is there a more efficient way to get those sub-scores?

[My code here is in Scala, but feel free to respond in Java if that's easier.]

**EDIT: Here's what things look like after following Robert Muir's suggestion.**

The query:

```
val query = new BooleanQuery
for ((subQuery, weight) <- ...) {
  val weightedQuery = new BoostedQuery(subQuery, new ConstValueSource(weight))
  query.add(weightedQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST)
}
```

The search:

```
val collector = new DocScoresCollector(nHits)
searcher.search(query, collector)
for (docScores <- collector.getDocSubScores) {
  ...
}
```

The collector:

```
class DocScoresCollector(maxSize: Int) extends Collector {
  var scorer: Scorer = null
  var subScorers: Seq[Scorer] = null
  val priorityQueue = new DocScoresPriorityQueue(maxSize)

  override def setScorer(scorer: Scorer): Unit = {
    this.scorer = scorer
    // a little reflection hackery is required here because of a bug in
    // BoostedQuery's scorer's getChildren method
    // https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-4261
    this.subScorers = scorer.getChildren.asScala.map(childScorer =>
      childScorer.child ...some hackery... ).toList
  }

  override def acceptsDocsOutOfOrder: Boolean = false

  override def collect(doc: Int): Unit = {
    this.scorer.advance(doc)
    val score = this.scorer.score
    val subScores = this.subScorers.map(_.score)
    priorityQueue.insertWithOverflow(DocScores(doc, score, subScores))
  }

  override def setNextReader(context: AtomicReaderContext): Unit = {}

  def getDocSubScores: Seq[DocScores] = {
    val buffer = Buffer.empty[DocScores]
    while (this.priorityQueue.size > 0) {
      buffer += this.priorityQueue.pop
    }
    buffer
  }
}

case class DocScores(doc: Int, score: Float, subScores: Seq[Float])

class DocScoresPriorityQueue(maxSize: Int) extends PriorityQueue[DocScores](maxSize) {
  def lessThan(a: DocScores, b: DocScores) = a.score < b.score
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a scorer navigation API: the basic idea is you write a collector and in its setScorer method, where normally you would save a reference to that Scorer to later score() each hit, you can now walk the tree of that Scorer's subscorers and so on.

Note that Scorers have pointers back to the Weight that created them, and the Weight back to the Query.

Using all of this, you can stash away references to the subscorers you care about in your setScorer method, e.g. all the ones created from TermQueries. Then when scoring hits, you could and investigate things like the freq() and score() of those nodes in your collector.

In the 3.x series this is a visitor API limited to boolean relationships, in the 4.x series (as of now only an alpha release), you can just get the child+relationship of each subscorer, so it can work with arbitrary queries (including custom ones you write or whatever).

Caveats:

- you will need to return false from acceptsDocsOutOfOrder in your collector, as your collector requires this document-at-a-time processing for this to work.

  you probably want a bugfix branch of the 3.6 series (http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/branches/lucene_solr_3_6/) or a snapshot of 4.x (http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/branches/branch_4x/). This is because this functionality generally didnt work since disjunctions (OR queries) always set their subscorers 'one doc ahead' of the current document until some things were fixed last week, and those fixes didnt make it in time for 3.6.1. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-3505 for more details.

  There aren't really any good examples, except some simple tests that sum up the term frequencies of all the leaf nodes (see below)

Tests:

- 4.x series: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/branches/branch_4x/lucene/core/src/test/org/apache/lucene/search/TestBooleanQueryVisitSubscorers.java

  3.x series: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/branches/lucene_solr_3_6/lucene/core/src/test/org/apache/lucene/search/TestBooleanQueryVisitSubscorers.java

Comment: Thanks for all the details. I started down the Collector path, but I couldn't figure out how to "walk the tree of that Scorer's subscorers". Could you give some example code on how to do that?

Comment: Take a look at those tests. in 4.x you call getChildren() on the scorer and navigate yourself. In 3.x you must use the visitor